# Android studio checkout from Version Control: Google Cloud

Tags: android-studio, version-control, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I uploaded an android studio project with VCS->Import Into Version Control->Upload Project to Google Cloud. The project is succesfully uploaded as I see it in the developer console. The promlem come when I try to Checkout it from my other pc.
I select the Google Project Id and choose clone, the I choose Create project from existing source and so on.. The problem is that Android Studio can't see that I have two modules and tells me to migrate to gradle but I don't know how to do it.. 
How can I migrate to gradle after the project is downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I did not commit the gradle build files, so when I checked out the project Android studio could not recognize it as a gradle built project. I just pushed the gradle files and checked out the proejct again and everyting worked.